# How can I unserstand working with transaction in spring framework environment?

Tags: sql, database, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I analyzed the Spring framework source code but I have not understood why the transaction was not worked properly.

I sent request packet with 32 threads to call buySth function (through the controller). I thought that insert select query was worked in one transaction so if the remainMoney is lower than 1000 then insert job will be stopped but the result was totally different. Insert job was not stopped when reaminMoney was zero.

Why the transaction was worked like that? I searched the internet to find the reason but I could not find it. Would you give me some advices?

I attached parts of the codes like below.

1) ServiceImpl (using @Transactional)

```
@Service ("testService")

public class testServiceImpl implements testService{

    ..........

   @Override

   @Transactional

   public void buySth(String id, int seq) throws Exception {

       ..........

       int result = sqlSession.insert("testMapper.insertTestSth", map);

   }

       ..............
```

2) Mapping file (using insert select query but select just used for checking the condition)

```
<insert id="insertTestSth" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">

   insert into dbo.TestSth (id, reductMoney, type, description)

   select #{id}, #{reductMoney}, #{type}, #{description} 

    where (

            select sum(nvl (initMoney, 0))-sum (nvl (reductMoney, 0)) as remainMoney 
              from dbo.TestSth where id = #{id}    

           ) > 1000

</insert>
```

3) Db-default isolation level: Read committed

Comment: "if the remainMoney is lower than 1000 then insert job will be stopped" Which part of your code is supposed to stop the insert?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I made a mistake. I modified the source code.